# Changing Subdomain from HTTPS to HTTP

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, ssl

Currently my main GoDaddy account has an SSL certificate, so by default all of my sites below automatically try and start with https://

So I have this in my htaccess file for all of my sites below and it works fine.

```
# All urls have www. in them
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomainname\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mydomainname.com/$1 [R=permanent,L]
```

However when i try and do a subdomain, ie

```
# Sub Domain Rewrite
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subname\.mydomainname\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://subname.mydomainname.com/$1 [R=permanent,L]
```

It doesn't seem to work, any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by `doesn't seem to work`? Can you provide details?

Comment: It brings up the security error and still goes to https

Comment: What is `DocumentRoot` of subdomain?

Comment: Is it same as `DocumentRoot` of main domain? Also can you post full .htaccess?

Comment: No, DocumentRoot for main domain is /clientsnow

And those are the full .htaccess with the exception of the domain names. @anubhava

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so it seems you need to place this rule in `accord/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Sub Domain Rewrite    
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subname\.mydomainname\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,NE,L]
```